# Using left join with where for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have a MySQL query which looks something like this:

```
Select * from T1,T2,T3
where t1.pk1 = t2.pk2
and t2.pk3 = t3.pk4
```

I need to join the above result set with another table T4 using left join (I need the complete result set from the above query but only the existing records from table T4). I tried this:

```
Select * from t1,t2,t3
left join t4
on t1.pk5 = t4.pk6 
where t1.pk1 = t2.pk2
and t2.pk3 = t3.pk4
```

But it didn't work....can someone help out with the semantics?

Comment: Hi. You do not need to ask on SO to find out how joins work. If read the manual you will find `,` has lower precedence than explicit `join`s. Morever you do not actually say what you output you want in this specific case. So all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't mix explicit and implicit JOIN

if you need  an exact match you must use an INNER JOIN  ..  if you have not always  exact mathc you must use LEFT JOIN

remember that the use of colums related  to left join table in where is equivalent to an INNER JOIN so

So your query shold be  equivalent to

```
Select t1.* , t2.*, t3.*, t4.*
from t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.pk1 = t2.pk2
INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.pk3 = t3.pk4
left join t4 on t1.pk5 = t4.pk6
```

If you  don't have the expected  result could be that you need  another INNER JOIN too for t4

```
Select t1.* , t2.*, t3.*, t4.*
from t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.pk1 = t2.pk2
INNER JOIN t3 ON t2.pk3 = t3.pk4
INNER JOIN t4 on t1.pk5 = t4.pk6
```

Answer (score 0):

since you need help with semantics, i have elaborated every line of code for your reference. 
1. when you need all the data from multiple tables, use--> select table_names.* and not select * from table1..table n
2. since we need all the data from these 4 tables, we use table.* , you can get individual columns using table_name.column_name
3. the tables are being connected on the basis of different column names, so we use JOIN and don't use UNION.
4. INNER JOIN - it will yield only those column values which are common to both tables.
5. OUTER JOIN - it will yield all those column values which are there in both tables based on the column name specified in join.

Check the below query, it should work fine on MYSQL.

```
select T1.* ,T2.* ,T3.* ,T4.*  
from (((T1 outer
join T2 ON T1.pk1 = T2.pk2) outer
join T3 ON T2.pk3 = T3.pk4) 
join T4 ON T1.pk5 = T4.pk6)
```